# How to tell when a vector (9-tuple) changes structure over time?

Tags: mathematics, limit-order-book

I have a 9-element vector I compute at any time T that is derived from the state of the order book. I plot the elements over time and get something like this:

[image]

I'm interested to see when the nature of the vector changes in relation to major turning points in the price series. Thngs I've looked at is the sum of all the elements or the delta between element 1 and element 0, the ratio of element 0 to the sum(of all elements). All plot and give me relatively interesting peaks and turning points that seem correlated to the price series.  Is there some more general transform or calculation I can make that can tell me when the vector undergoes a change in structure?